# Creating an UPDATE script in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table in SQL Server 2005 filled with data.  Is there a method by which I can generate update statements including the data in it?

Comment: I need to auto generate the script complete with all the data inside the table.  I have one table with the correct data and another table in another system with wrong data in the table.  What I need to do is auto generate an update script that will allow me to update the wrong table with the data from the correct table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice free tool here http://www.lss.co.uk/Products/LiveDataScript/

Comment: +1, because I wrote it :) - the site is down now, but I'll try to make it available on my blog (when I finally manage to get that back up and running...)

Comment: The link for LiveDataScript is now here: http://www.goatly.net/downloads/livedatascript

Comment: This tool only creates `INSERT` scripts, not `UPDATE` ones as the OP asked for. I also need a tool to create UPDATE scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find any better solution, try this:

```
SELECT 
  'UPDATE [Table] (field1, field2, field3) Values (' 
     + field1 + ', ' 
     + field2 + ', ' 
     + field3 + ')'
FROM [Table]
```

I know, not nice.

Answer (score 0):

Go here and get the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express [SSMSE Download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)

After installing you can then connect to your database with the tool and generate several types of "vanilla" scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean data on the same row, just use it in the Update Statement

```
Update MyTable Set ColumnA = ColumnB + ColumnC
```

If you want to use data from other rows, you probably have to join it back to it's self

```
Update a 
Set ColumnA = b.ColumnD
From MyTable a
Join MyTable b on a.ColumnB = b.ColumnC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
  'UPDATE [Table] SET field1 = ' + field1  + ' , field2 = ' + field2 + ' , field3 = ' + field3 + ' WHERE <condition> ' FROM <Table>
```

Use extra single Quotes wherever string data is updated.